# Format values in SQL query as numbers to export them to Excel

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE Logistics (
    country TEXT,
    Costs_Inbound CHAR(255),
    Costs_Storage CHAR(255),
    Costs_Outbound CHAR(255)
);


INSERT INTO Logistics 
(country, Costs_Inbound, Costs_Storage, Costs_Outbound)
VALUES 
("DE", "5000", "300", "600500.815523"),
("NL", "3000", "650", "250452.454"), 
("FR", "4000", "120", "750060.935775272");
```

and I use the following query to get `Costs_Outbound` from the table:

```
SELECT country,
TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 255 ,'DE_DE')) Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

The `SQL fiddle` you can find [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28c574/11). 
All this works fine so far.

---

However, when I export the values to Excel they are conisered as text and not as numbers. 
 Is there something I need to change in the FORMAT function so they are considered as numbers also for the Excel Export?

---

*I am not sure if the SQL fiddle that I created fully replicates the problem that I have in my original case using MySQL Workbench since SQL fiddle does not seem to have an Excel export function but I still hope you have an idea how to solve my issue.*

Comment: You say _I export the values to Excel_  like that is a MySQL thing. It isn't. What are you _actually_ doing to achieve this?

Comment: The numbers exported have thousands separators. That could be why Excel interprets them as text instead of numbers. Also, look at the CSV (I presume) to see if the column is exported with quotes.

Comment: Why not just use `sum()`?  Changing the data type to a string (using `format()`) is likely to cause downstream applications to treat the column as a string.

Comment: Also, when importing into Excel, you can set each column to a specific type instead of "auto"

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I want that the values are in the DE_DE format and also considered as numbers. That is the reason why I did not only use the sum () function. However, since I am newbie to SQL I am not sure if this is possible to achieve or if I need to make any of these adjustments in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Excel to recognize your German number format, you might need to check that your regional Windows settings are also specifying numbers in that format, since Excel is automatically using the Windows setting for this. If this is so, there's no setting in Excel itself that can do the same thing for you, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Just import as it in excel and then, using excel formatting options change the col to number.